# How to constrain type family to Show

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on an interpreter, which should be able to handle multiple variations of a language.

Therefore I'm designing my AST with type families (a simple example is given below).
How do I tell GHC that my type families need to have Show (and Eq) instances?
I have tried to use StandaloneDeriving, but can't find out how to define the dependency/ constraint.

```hs
-- Types.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Types where

data Statement v = CommonStatement (CommonStatement v)
                 | VariantStatement (VariantStatement v)
                deriving (Show)
data CommonStatement v = Skip deriving (Show)
data family VariantStatement v
```

```hs
-- Coroutine.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Coroutine (module Coroutine, module Types) where

import Types

newtype Coroutine = Coroutine [Statement Coroutine]
data instance VariantStatement Coroutine = SomeStatement deriving (Show)
```

When trying to build this (with stack and resolver lts-16.16), it fails since it can't deduce an instance of Show for (VariantStatement v):

```sh
    • No instance for (Show (VariantStatement v))
        arising from the first field of ‘VariantStatement’
          (type ‘VariantStatement v’)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Show (Statement v))
  |
7 |                 deriving (Show)
  |                           ^^^^
```

Comment: Could you not just define `VariantStatement` as a `type family` instead? That would let you do `data SomeStatement = SomeStatement deriving (Show)`, and then `type instance VariantStatement Coroutine = SomeStatement`.

Comment: Oh, and also, I just discovered [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Type_class_instances_of_family_instances) in the documentation, which may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: The Trees that Grow paper about extensible ASTs might be relevant https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/11/trees-that-grow.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just a matter of chasing down and squashing the errors:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}
main= print SomeStatement

data Statement v
  = CommonStatement (CommonStatement v)
  | VariantStatement (VariantStatement v)

-- StandaloneDeriving and UndecidableInstances
-- are required for this one.
deriving instance Show (VariantStatement v) => Show (Statement v)

data CommonStatement v = Skip deriving (Show)

data family VariantStatement v

newtype Coroutine = Coroutine [Statement Coroutine]

data instance VariantStatement Coroutine = SomeStatement deriving Show
```

Comment: In my experience, this kind of code also often runs into the need for `QuantifiedConstraints`. For example, say you had `data Block f v = Block (f (Statement v))` which might be instantiated with `[]` initially and then `Vector` to save some memory; you’d want to derive `Show` *given* that the container is showable *if* its elements are showable, which you can phrase as: `deriving instance (forall a. Show a => Show (f a)) => Show (Block f v)`.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I don't see the need in your example. What's wrong with `deriving instance Show (f (Statement v)) => Show (Block f v)` in that case? It's a strictly more general instance and avoids the pitfalls of quantified constraints. I'd only reach for those if I really needed the extra polymorphism to write correct or efficient code.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I personally consider the `QuantifiedConstraints` language feature ill-behaved, mostly because of the problems of local overlap and especially the generally nasty interactions with `Coercible`. So I'll use its power when I really need to, but I prefer to steer well clear the rest of the time. Hopefully these problems will eventually be resolved somehow. The most likely way seems to be finding a way for the user to guide constraint resolution in ambiguous cases.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on the context; that is, whether you need this instance depends on whether the users of `Block` want the extra generality, which depends on factors I dunno if I could adequately explain in just a comment. But I thought I’d just leave a note about the extension for posterity, since it has come up for me before with similar code.

Comment: I often use `QuantifiedConstraints` to get *around* issues with `Coercible`, actually, particularly the first-order/monomorphic nature of roles, but I agree it can be frustrating—it’s not always intuitive when “I know, I’ll use `QuantifiedConstraints`!” is going to help, and when it’s going to end in “Now I have an infinite family of overlapping problems”.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I've played around a lot with quantified constraints and `Coercible`. I could write really cool things that were exactly what I wanted to say, but then they'd turn out to be unusable because GHC stubbornly insisted on using a global coercion axiom with stronger constraints than the local one I was trying to introduce. Grrrrrr!